# Laravel mail does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send email to multiple receivers and I get the error below

> Address in mailbox given [2@test.com,3@test.com,4@test.com] does not
> comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

This is how my data looks like:

```
array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "xlhKNDnqAuvQpurPpDM2eGseNanUm5P1NBbPA71Z"
  "from" => "test@test.com"
  "mainpeople" => "1@test.com" //to
  "ccpeople" => "2@test.com,3@test.com,4@test.com" //cc
  "subject" => "testing mail"
  "messagenote" => "<p>this is a test mail.<br></p>"
]
```

#### Code

```
$data = array(
  'from' => $request->from,
  'to' => $request->mainpeople,
  'ccpeople' => array($request->ccpeople),
  'subject' => $request->subject,
  'messagenote' => $request->messagenote,
);

Mail::to($data['to'])->cc($data['ccpeople'])->send(new ComposeMail($data));
```

Also, I tried to loop `CC` emails but the result was the same:

```
$data = array(
    'from' => $request->from,
    'to' => $request->mainpeople,
    'ccpeople' => array($request->ccpeople),
    'subject' => $request->subject,
    'messagenote' => $request->messagenote,
);

foreach($data['ccpeople'] as $people){
    $cc = $people;
}

Mail::to($data['to'])->cc($cc)->send(new ComposeMail($data));
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It looks like you're passing a string of comma separated email address for the CC header line. These most likely need to be an array instead.

Comment: @fubar i even placed my code like `[$data['ccpeople']]` yet no luck

Comment: That's just making an array with one string of comma separated email addresses. Each address needs to be in it's own index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `array()` directly on string to convert it to array:

your `$data` should be as it is:

```
$data = array(
  'from' => $request->from,
  'to' => $request->mainpeople,
  'ccpeople' => $request->ccpeople,
  'subject' => $request->subject,
  'messagenote' => $request->messagenote,
);
```

Instead of

```
foreach($data['ccpeople'] as $people){
    $cc = $people;
}
```

try `explode()` like below :

```
$cc = explode(',',$data['ccpeople']);
```

and pass it to your mail function:

```
Mail::to($data['to'])->cc($cc)->send(new ComposeMail($data));
```

Comment: it says `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Comment: Ok it sends now to cc emails as well but if my cc emails are empty it returns `Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.` how to avoid that? I need cc to be optional

Comment: In that case, you need to apply `if` condition that `isset($data['ccpeople'])` then use `cc()` function `Mail::to($data['to'])->cc($cc)->send(new ComposeMail($data));` else you need to use `Mail::to($data['to'])->send(new ComposeMail($data));` without `cc()` function.